# Problem: after importing and exporting .nif in Blender, automatic (forced) merging (drawing) of vertices occurs

Tags: mesh

Need help from experts!
Hello everybody!

Problem: after importing and exporting .nif in Blender, automatic (forced) merging (drawing) of vertices occurs.
All torn (tattered, full of holes) clothes become without holes and tears, the lower part of the fur is rounded and smoothed, the hair turns into long rags.

To display .nif models I use OutfitStudio.
Here's what happens:

Before Blender's .nif import and export changes:
https://ibb.co/c6MBKLq
https://ibb.co/wWZr6C2
https://ibb.co/Thxt21F
https://ibb.co/0B7Cb0y

After changing the .nif import and export in Blender:
https://ibb.co/cDrYbbw
https://ibb.co/cYjV2YS
https://ibb.co/Y26Tvd7
https://ibb.co/4SqqGLm

P.S. The difference is not what to save(export) provided(object data setting) "pose position" or that "rest position".
Worth Blender v3.1.2

Comment: Blender has an auto-merge setting.  You can check in edit mode to see if you have it enabled.  its the icon next to the Options menu on the far right of the top menu in the 3D viewport.  Is that on?

Comment: Marty Fouts, Greetings!
Checked. These settings are disabled by default.
Provided that it is disabled, forced merging still occurs.
Here is a confirmation screenshot:
https://ibb.co/kqnbsXR

Comment: Are there other solutions to this problem?

Comment: I've never seen this problem before, so I'm at a loss. Sorry.  There must be a solutions, so perhaps someone will post an answer.